# Metric spaces inside of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $Y$ ⊂ $X$ and consider the metric space $(Y, d)$.

- Show that every open set $U$ in $Y$ has the form $U$ = $V$ ∩ $Y$ for an open set $V$ ⊂ $X$.
- Show that $Y$ is compact in $(Y, d)$ if and only if every collection of open sets { V<sub>k</sub> } <sub>k ∈ K</sub> in $X$ that
  covers $Y$ has a finite subcover.

I'm beyond confused on how to go about this problem. I mostly understand what it is that I have to show, but have no idea how to show any of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: 1) $U\subset Y$ is open implies that $U$ is a union of open balls in $Y$. What happens if you take the same open balls, but see them as balls in $X$?

2) If $Y$ is compact, then $\{V_k \cap Y\}_K$ is an open cover of $Y$ by opens in $Y$, so by compactness... If every cover of $Y$ by opens of $X$ admits a finite subcover, then use part 1) to show that $Y$ is compact.